# Tomcat memory leak with netty

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty, tomcat8

I'm using Tomcat 8.0 server along with https://github.com/lafaspot/imapnio

which internally uses Netty for NIO.

I get the following Exceptions while shutting down tomcat.

> WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely
>   to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method) 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269) 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79) 
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86) 
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97) 
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:731) 
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391) 
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 16-Sep-2018 05:14:04.319 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely
>   to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method) 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269) 
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79) 
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86) 
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97) 
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:731) 
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391) 
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)

I use the following code to shutdown Netty.

```
Future<?> future = this.group.shutdownGracefully();
try {
    future.await();
}catch(InterruptedException e) {

}
```

Can you please help me fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you only shut down the netty instance once? This is definitely not great, but if this issue only happens in server shutdown, then the JVM should exit... meaning memory leak is not a big issue.

Comment: I also the shutdown a ThreadPool which uses Executor Service and the SchedulerService. Is there a way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you try to run `FastThreadLocal.removeAll()` as last action ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it. But it did not work